# Let $a_1, a_2, \dots$ be a sequence such that $a_i \ge \varepsilon >0$ for all $i = 1,2,\dots$. Show that $\sum_{i \in \{1,2,\dots\}} a_i = \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $a_1, a_2, \dots$ be a sequence such that $a_i \ge \varepsilon >0$ for all $i = 1,2,\dots$. Show that $\sum_{i \in \{1,2,\dots\}} a_i = \infty$.

If I let $I = \{1,2,\dots\}$ and take $I_n = \{1,2,\dots, n\}$, then $I_n \subset I$. Now if I can show that $$\sum_{i \in I_n} a_i = \infty$$ then would it follow that $$\sum_{i \in I} a_i = \infty?$$

For the sum $\sum_{i \in I_n} a_i$ I have that $$\sum_{i \in I_n} a_i \ge \sum_{i \in I_n} \varepsilon = n\varepsilon \text{, but $n$ could be as big as we want so this would tend to $\infty$?}$$

Comment: By definition the sum over $I$ is the limit of the sum over $I_n$. So you are done.

Comment: Your last statement is correct, that is called the “Archimedean property”.

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall \epsilon\in\mathbb R^+:\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\epsilon=\infty$$

Using [direct comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test), we know $$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i\geq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\epsilon\Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your thoughts are right. Alternatively, you can argue that since $a_n \ge \varepsilon > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n \ge \varepsilon \ne 0$. Hence, the series diverges.